# Is there any way to use IO Bool in if-statement without binding to a name in haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads

If I've got a function that returns `IO Bool` (specifically an `atomically`), is there any way to use the return value directly in the `if` statement, without binding?

So currently I've got

```
ok <- atomically $ do
  ...
if (ok) then do
  ...
else do
  ...
```

Is it at all possible to write this as something like

```
if (*some_operator_here* atomically $ do
      ...) then do
  ...
else do
  ...
```

I was hoping there'd be a way to use something like `<-` anonymously, i.e., `if (<- atomically ...)` but so far no such luck.

Similarly on getLine, is it possible to write something like

```
if ((*operator* getLine) == "1234") then do ...
```

Related addendum--what is the type of `(<-)`?  I can't get it to show up in ghci.  I'm assuming it's `m a -> a`, but then that would mean it could be used outside of a monad to escape that monad, which would be unsafe, right?  Is `(<-)` not a function at all?

Comment: To answer your latter question, `(<-)` is not a function or expression and is built-in syntax that is part of "do" notation.  It desugars to a call to `(>>=)` under the hood and you can read [this](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html) to learn more about how that desugaring works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `ifM` from [`Control.Conditional`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cond/0.4/doc/html/Control-Conditional.html) if that suits your purpose and its not even hard to write a similar function.

Just to give you example

```
import Control.Conditional
import Control.Monad

(==:) :: ( Eq a,Monad m) => m a -> m a -> m Bool
(==:) = liftM2 (==)

main = ifM (getLine ==: getLine) (print "hit") (print "miss")
```

I think there are ways using rebindable syntax extension that you can even use `if c then e1 else e2` like syntax for `ifM` but it is not worth the effort to try that.

Answer (score 7):

With GHC 7.6 and the [`LambdaCase`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#lambda-case) language extension, you can write

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

import System.Directory

main = do
    doesFileExist "/etc/passwd" >>= \case
        True ->  putStrLn "Yes"
        False -> putStrLn "No"
```

It is not exactly `if..then..else`, but closer enough, does not require binding to the result, and some people (not me) say that `if..then..else` is bad style in Haskell anyways.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. Well, to be honest, there is a 'hack' that will allow you to at least write code like this and get it to compile, but the results will almost certainly not be what you wanted or expected.

Why is this not possible? Well, for one thing a value of type `IO Bool` does not in any sense contain a value of type `Bool`. Rather it is an 'action' that when performed will return a value of type `Bool`. For another thing, if this were possible, it would allow you to hide side-effects inside what appears to be pure code. This would violate a core principal of Haskell. And Haskell is very principled.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate. His original code is clearly using do-notation, which means the results of the if statement are already in IO as appropriate. My understanding is that he just wants to use some operator like `<$>` or `>>=` for functions that would just work with the if-statement.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you think is inaccurate. If you believe that something like what OP was asking _is_ possible (using the `if` expression), please give an example.